# Is one or ones correct when mixing countable and uncountable forms of a noun?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

Is the sentence "Tanya likes coffee, especially one made by Victoria." grammatically correct and why? I've been thinking of substituting one with "ones", "those" and "that" but I am not sure which is correct.

Comment: Good question. I suspect *that* works best, but I look forward to the academic answer.

Comment: 'especially _such_ made by Victoria'.

Comment: Neither works here as 'one/s' cannot refer to the non-count usage 'coffee'. << Tanya likes coffee. She especially likes it made the way Vicoria makes it. >>

Comment: Tanya likes coffee, especially the way/when Victoria makes it.

Comment: 'Tanya likes a coffee, especially ...'.